# Updating a custom video timeline in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management, html5-video, settimeout

I have some code that calculates the current position of a video. I've added a custom timeline at the bottom of the video for seeking. The custom timeline is just a long `div`. I want to display the current position of the video on my timeline with a marker. When the video is playing, the marker should be moving.

I've already calculated the marker positioning on the timeline but I need help with updating its position.

What is the best way to do this? The simplest way would be the code below which just checks the videos position every tenth of a second and updates the marker accordingly. It could possibly be the best way. But I don't know if this may cause problems as it will be repeating every tenth of a second. I don't know that much about memory management. Will this have a big effect on memory and slow the site down? Your input is much appreciated.

```
var setTimer = function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
      updateTimeline()
      setTimer()
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: this should be fine, depending on how much other stuff you have going on. why not give it a shot and see if you can discern any problems?

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything I should be watching out for other than general slowdown?